# Python pandas plot scatter datetime error

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scatter-plot

I want a scatter plot where x-axis is a `datetime`, y-axis is an `int`. And I have only a few of datapoints that are discrete and not continuous, so I don't want to connect datapoints.

My DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':[dt.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,0), dt.datetime(2016,1,4,0,0,0),
    dt.datetime(2016,1,9,0,0,0)], 'value':[10, 7, 8]})
```

If I use "normal" plot than I got a "line" figure:

```
df.plot(x='datetime', y='value')
```

But how can I plot only the dots? This gives error:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='datetime', y='value')
KeyError: 'datetime'
```

Of course I can use some cheat to get the result I want, for example:

```
df.plot(x='datetime', y='value', marker='o', linewidth=0)
```

But I don't understand why the `scatter` version does not work...

Thank you for help!

Comment: See more helpful answers, providing a better date conversion to numeric or using pyplot.plot_date() instead,  at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Scatter plot can be drawn by using the DataFrame.plot.scatter()  method. Scatter plot requires **numeric** columns for x and y axis. These
can be specified by x and y keywords each.*

Alternative Approach:

```
In [71]: df['day'] = df['datetime'].dt.day

In [72]: df.plot.scatter(x='day', y='value')
Out[72]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x25440a1bc88>
```

[image]
    ￼

Comment: Thank you! So it is not a bug, it is a feature. Nice ;-)

Comment: But day is not monotonic, unless everything happens in the same month....